# Organizar capacidades e níveis de usuários wordpress (sem plugin)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Primeiro irei explicar o cenário, quero fazer um sistema onde terão 4 tipos diferentes de pessoas acessando.
O Administrador, "moderadores", autores, e parceiros.
Eu queria usar o próprio painel admin do wordpress para tudo, então criei um `post_type` parceiro. Neste sistema, cada parceiro pode ter uma página no site. E também, usar o sistema de posts (blog) padrão do wordpress.
Então para gerênciar tudo isso pensei em alterar as `roles` existentes para ficarem organizadas dessa maneira:

```
ROLES:
  ADMIN -
    all

  Editor -
    Pode Cadastrar novo post
    Ver todos os posts de qualquer autor
    Editar o post de qualquer autor
    Publicar posts e deixar para revisão pendente

    Cadastrar página de parceiro
    Ver todas as páginas de parceiros
    Editar as páginas de parceiros de qualquer autor
    Publicar página de parceiro e deixar para revisão pendente

  Autor -
    Pode cadastrar novo post
    ver apenas seus proprios posts
    editar apenas seus proprios posts
    não pode publicar (sempre lançar como revisão)

  Colaborador -
    Ver apenas as suas página de parceiro
    Editar apenas sua página de parceiro
    Não pode publicar página de parceiro (sempre lançar como revisão)

  Subscriber -
    Nada!
```

Ai surgiu a dúvida, esta é a melhor maneira de organizar isso? Ou seria melhor criar novas roles (pelo menos para gerênciar os parceiros).

E além disso, agora dúvidas técnicas, para criar `capabilities` novas em um custom `post_type`, seria passando o argumento `capabilities` dessa maneira:

```
'capabilities' => array(
  'edit_post' => 'edit_partner',
  'edit_posts' => 'edit_partners',
  'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_other_partners',
  'publish_posts' => 'publish_partners',
  'read_post' => 'read_partner',
  'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_partners',
  'delete_post' => 'delete_partner'
)
```

E depois adicionar em cada role:

```
$admins = get_role( 'administrator' );
$admins->add_cap( 'edit_post' );
$admins->add_cap( 'edit_posts' );
$admins->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' );
$admins->add_cap( 'publish_posts' );
$admins->add_cap( 'read_post' );
$admins->add_cap( 'read_private_posts' );
$admins->add_cap( 'delete_post' );

$editors = get_role( 'editor' );
$editors->add_cap( 'edit_post' );
$editors->add_cap( 'edit_posts' );
$editors->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' );
$editors->add_cap( 'publish_posts' );
$editors->add_cap( 'read_post' );
$editors->add_cap( 'read_private_posts' );
$editors->add_cap( 'delete_post' );

$partners = get_role( 'subscriber' );
$partners->add_cap( 'edit_post' );
```

Pois tentei exatamente como mostrei acima, mas ele não cadastrava o custom post_type com o argumento `capabilities`.

Resumindo: 
Não sei se é certo mexer nas `capabilities` das `roles` padrões do wordpress, e nem exatamente como fazer isso
E também não sei como dar permissão apenas para um `custom post_type`, eu não queria que os usuários `Colaboradores` pudessem ver/alterar/editar os posts normais, apenas o `post_type parceiro`, e ainda sim, apenas o vínculado ao usuário dele. E nem que os usuários `Autores` pudessem ver/editar/alterar o `post_type parceiro`.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login de usuário individual no *Wordpress*

Você pode baixar um plugin para roler.. outro para redirecionamento e criar um template novo assim

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Página de login
*/
get_header();

// Dados do formulário de login
$argumentos_login = array(
    'echo'           => true,
    'redirect' => ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
    'form_id'        => 'tp-login-form',
    'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
    'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
    'id_username'    => 'tp-user-login',
    'id_password'    => 'tp-user-pass',
    'id_remember'    => 'tp-remember-me',
    'id_submit'      => 'tp-submit-btn',
    'remember'       => true,
    'value_username' => null,
    'value_remember' => false,
);
?>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.tp-login-container {
    text-align: center;
}
-->
</style>


<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="tp-login-container">

    <?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ): ?>

        <?php wp_login_form( $argumentos_login );?>

    <?php 
    else:

        // Usuário atual
        $usuario_atual = wp_get_current_user();

        // URL da página SAIR DA AREA VIP
        $pagina_login = ' http://localhost/natureza/';

        // Mensagem para o usuário
        echo '<p>Você já fez login <b>' . $usuario_atual->user_firstname . '</b>.';
        echo ' Clique <a href="' . wp_logout_url( $pagina_login ) . '">aqui</a>';
        echo ' para sair.';
        echo '</p>'; 

    endif; // is_user_logged_in
    ?>

</div> <!-- tp-login-container -->

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

..

Depois é só criar a pagina nova .. add o template novo .. daí o login está pronto

Depois você vai em *Usuários* > *Role* > *Add role*, crie uma role com o nome do usuário.. ou nome do departamento.. o role pode ser individual ou para grupos.

Se for para usuário único é importante criar uma role individual se não, pode ser uma para muitos usuários.

Criamos a role(papel ou função de cada usuário) com o nome do usuário, pois cada um tem o seu acesso para sua área reservada.

Depois cadastramos o usuário e damos permissão, tem vários tipos de permissões, para assinante eu deixei marcada só a opção *Read*, o usuário estando cadastrado o próximo passo é fazer o redirecionamento, como o role(papel) já foi criado no primeiro passo, o último passo é só adicionar o redirecionamento com um plugin de *redirect* que da certo. Pergunte-me como.. rerere